# Use javascript to count immediate child elements of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, count, parent-child

I can get the count of all descendants of an element, but I can't seem to target just the *immediate* children. Here's what I have at the moment.

```
var sectionCount = document.getElementById("window").getElementsByTagName("section").length;
```

I've played with other stuff and different syntax, but I can't seem to get it.

The jQuery equivalent would be:

```
var sectionCount = $("#window > section").length;
```

But I need to do this javascript only.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the DOM selector interface ([querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.querySelectorAll)).

```
var selectionCount = document.querySelectorAll("#window > section").length;
```

If you want a backwards compatible solution, loop through `childNodes` and count element nodes.

```
var w = document.getElementById('window');
var count = 0; // this will contain the total elements.
for (var i = 0; i < w.childNodes.length; i++) {
    var node = w.childNodes[i];
    if (node.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE && node.nodeName == "SECTION") {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: However, this is not compatible in a prehistorical context. IE IEn.

Comment: @Caspar - prehistoric lol, it wasn't that long ago. Added a solution for IE.

Comment: Sorry for responding so late. I just realize now that it does in fact error in IE. It says "Node is undefined". It shows up on the line where the 'if' statement is. Does something need to be switched around or is there something I should do to define the node.

Comment: Replace `Node.ELEMENT_NODE` with the integer `1`.

Comment: Log the values of `node.nodeType`, and `node.nodeName` and see if they match `1` and `"SECTION"` respectively.

Comment: Yes, they equal `1` and `SECTION` (it didn't return quotes on the SECTION)

Comment: Sorry, quotes won't be there. that seems weird if both values are equal, count must be incremented. I can't see why it is not.

Comment: Is it possible it's just because I'm using an html5 section tag? I don't know if that would prevent IE from counting it right.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, especially since you're seeing the tag name `SECTION` logged. It's basically a comparison of an integer and a string from that point on. Maybe log the result of all three expressions and see if they're true - `node.nodeType == 1`, `node.nodeName == "SECTION"`, and the combined version `node.nodeType == 1 && node.nodeName == "SECTION"`

Comment: Yeah, something is definitely up. I put the log in the for loop and it spat out alternating answers `3 == 1
#text == SECTION
false
1 == 1
SECTION == SECTION
true`

Comment: Sorry the formatting in the comments isnt so good. It shows `3 == 1 #text == SECTION false` and then the next 3 are  `1 == 1 SECTION == SECTION true` and it alternates between those 2 outputs as it goes through the loop

Comment: Don't worry about the `#text`. An empty whitespace is also a node (text node), and can show up in the `childNodes` array. Ignoring the text nodes, all three checks should be true whenever you see `node.nodeName == "SECTION"` to be true.

Comment: Sorry, I only put in the first half of the equations and made the second half text. I thought we were just comparing and not looking for the true/false. I put in the full lines. It came back `false false false`

Comment: Sorry! In regards to that last comment, I put it in the wrong spot, I was rearranging things trying to make it work. It alternates between `true true true` and `false false false`

Comment: No no no, they're all coming back as true. I'm sorry. I had them place just outside the 'if' statement. Putting them inside. everything comes back as true

Comment: hmm.. if you're getting inside the if loop, then count has to get incremented. Are you sure there is no global variable named `count`? The problem seems to be somewhere else.

Comment: I do use `count` after as the number to stop a `For` loop. Here is one thing I've noticed though. If I log the `node.nodeType` outside the if statement, it comes back as `1 3 1 3` etc. through the loop while `node.ELEMENT_NODE` stays `1` so the if statement is ending up `true false true false` etc.

Comment: I think I will just have to concede IE7 Browser support. Not that I'm too beat up about it. Thanks for all your help Anurag. I really appreciate the support