# Javascript - child node count

Tags: javascript, dom

```
<ul>
    <li>Array1</li>
    <li>Array2</li>
    <li id="element">Array3</li>
</ul>
<script>
   var temp = document.getElementById('element').parentNode;
   child = temp.childNodes;
   console.log(temp.length);
</script>
```

I need to get the child node length using element id. My code returns 7 as a result but I have only 3 nodes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use javascript to count immediate child elements of an element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685184/use-javascript-to-count-immediate-child-elements-of-an-element) -- please use the search before you ask a new question.

Comment: I accept you.. But I need pure javascript answer not jquery

Comment: If you read the answer carefully, you will see that it does not use jQuery at all/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`childNodes` gets **all** existing childNodes, including text nodes! In your example markup, you have your three "regular nodes" and 4 text nodes - the linebreaks - resulting in a total of 7 child nodes.

What you instead want is `.children.length` or `.childElementCount` (not supported in IE<9) to only fetch "actual" nodes:

```js
let temp = document.getElementById('element').parentNode;
console.log(temp.children.length);
// or the following
console.log(temp.childElementCount);
```

Comment: @KarthickV use `.children` this will return a html-collection and has better support. See [docu here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Element.children)

Comment: @KarthickV one important note: children us the right use, but it is buggy in older IEs - it counts comment nodes `<!-- comment -->` too! So be aware of that.

Comment: It doesn't work in IE 8 [http://jsfiddle.net/uyfPf/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/uyfPf/2/)

Comment: @JulienCh probably bc `childElementCount` isn't supported by IE8, you'll have to rely on `children.length` for older browsers

Answer (score 7):

`childNodes` returns the 3 list items, their text content and the whitespace between them (not in all browsers, though). Three alternatives:

1. FF and Chrome: `elem.childElementCount` (will return 3)
2. IE (&& FF AFAIK): `elem.childNodes.length` (===3)
3. Old IE: `elem.children.length`

Comment: @KarthickV: I checked the `childNodes.length`, it doesn't work in chrome (don't know what I was thinking) edited my answer... also: Who downvoted my answer, and why?

Comment: it works fine for me (chrome:temp.childElementCount) .. dont know who down voted.. Will give one up vote..Thanks for your valuable answer

Comment: I have no problem with downvotes, if I said something wrong. It would, however, be nice to know what my mistake was (if any). @Christoph: I don't accuse anyone, and fyi: I don't downvote out of spite, if that's what you were thinking

Answer (score 2):

The childrenNodes property include all types of nodes: TEXT_NODE, ELEMENT_NODE, COMMEN_NODE, etc....

You need to count the number of elements, here is [an example solution](http://jsfiddle.net/88fky/) based on DOM that should work in all engines:

```
var temp = document.getElementById('element').parentNode;
var children = temp.childNodes;
console.log(children.length); // 7

function countElements(children) {
  var count=0;
  for (var i=0, m=children.length; i<m; i++) 
     if (children[i].nodeType===document.ELEMENT_NODE) 
         count++;
  return count;
}
console.info(countElements (children));​ // 3
```

**EDIT**

Similarly if you want a function to retrieve all children Elements only using DOM, here is a function:

```
function childElements(node) {
  var elems = new Array();
  var children = node.childNodes;

    for (var i=0,i < children.length ; i++) {
         if (children[i].nodeType===document.ELEMENT_NODE) {
             elems.push(children[i]);
             return elems;
          }
         }
     }

console.info(childElements(temp).length);​ //3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a list of all nested DOM nodes, you can use this code snippet:

```js
function getNestedElements(node) {
  const elems = [];
  const children = node.childNodes;

  for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    if (children[i].nodeType === document.ELEMENT_NODE) {
      elems.push(children[i], ...getNestedElements(children[i]));
    }
  }
  return elems;
}
```

This is a modified version of @julien-ch [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11776810/1065780)