# How to count number of rows in a table when table row is added dynamically

Tags: javascript

How to count number of rows after adding rows dynamically. My table rows are adding cloning method.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685184/use-javascript-to-count-immediate-child-elements-of-an-element

Comment: I doubt it matters if this is a duplicate. This shows no research at all.

Comment: @Aravinth Well, "*then leave it*" isn't how this community works, which is to self-moderate. The downvotes suggest there's an issue with the quality of your question and iGanja's comment frankly does lead into what that is -- "[*Include: -- A reasonable explanation of what your question is. **Add as much detail as you can**. -- Any background research you've tried but wasn't enough to solve your problem.*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error)" Otherwise, "[*If you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer.*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"

Comment: @Aravinth Well, it's certainly on-topic for SO, but it is also a bit shy of details explaining the context in which you need a solution to work. Example: if it's important enough to mention "*after adding rows dynamically*," it may be worthwhile including a sample/snippet of the code that performs that. In general, at least including a failing attempt at solving an issue can show that we're assisting you rather than working for you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DOM element for the `<table>` will have a [`rows` collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement.rows):

```
document.getElementById('table-id').rows.length;
```

You can also [select the rows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelectorAll) in [supporting browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector):

```
document.querySelectorAll('#table-id > tr').length;
```

Or if you're using a library such as jQuery:

```
$('#table-id > tr').length;
```

Comment: I am not sure rows.length is not work

Comment: @Arut It can work: http://jsfiddle.net/coiscir/VyUgT/

Comment: @JonathanLonowski fine .

Comment: @JonathanLonowski great work jonathan.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski thank you for solve my problem.