# getting child count using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Can anyone please tell me how to get the count of the child within the main div using javascript like as shown below

```
<div ng-transclude="">
        <input type="text" ng-model="user" class="ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid">
</div>
```

Count = 1

```
<div ng-transclude="">
        <input type="text" ng-model="user" class="ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid">
        <input type="text" ng-model="place" class="ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid">
</div>
```

Count = 2

Comment: what is your concern ?, its obvious you are using angular, so why you need this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the built-in implementation of [**`jqLite`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) in `angular`, here in your case is `.find()` method would be useful if you need to have like this:

```
var title = element.find('input').length; // <---update this
alert("input length is ====>"+title);
```

### [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/JRuhNLS90v4mJcvLuy2B?p=preview)

Comment: @AlexMan see this [`jqLite` from here.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Answer (score 2):

Using javascript:

```
var childs = document.getElementById("id").children.length;
```

Answer (score 1):

var child = $("maindaiv").children().length;

Comment: jQuery IS Javascript.

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685184/use-javascript-to-count-immediate-child-elements-of-an-element. might help

Comment: Hmm.. Not sure jQuery complicates things - after all, the author is using Angular, so jqLite is already loaded.  Just saying that, technically, jQuery is just Javascript.

Comment: Shush, stop. Be more professional. Especially @MikeAnte, really.

Answer (score 1):

Quick Answer: Using pure JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('myElementId').childNodes.length
```

**Note** the text element is considered as node also

#### Update

the element parameters in angular is already a jQuery Lite object, so you can rewrite it like this

```
var childrenCount = element[0].childNodes.length;
```

Comment: Of course, that assumes an `id` attribute is added to the `div`.

Comment: @Ahmad i have edited my question, its an angularjs, within the link function i want to get the child count

Comment: `childNodes` is provide also element `<TextNode>`, hope length double

Answer (score 1):

See like bellow

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].children.length
```

Comment: @AlexMan in that fiddle you are saying `element.html().children().count` Say just `element.children.length`, updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/akxp66wd/2/

Comment: within that `<div ng-transclude></div>` there is only one child node right

Comment: @AlexMan I'm not much familiar with `directives` I given answer, because it was a JS question and it solved the js problem.